# Storing Symfony 2 cache elsewere?

Tags: caching, symfony

Is there a way to store symfony 2 cache (app/cache) somewhere else other than the filesystem? Memcache, S3, or something? Any built-in option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only move it outside of the project directory by overloading getCacheDir() method in the AppKernel class.

What's the point of moving it to Memcache? Contents of this directory is most of the time "compiled" classes and templates. Those files are put into memory anyway (APC does that).

**Edit**: On development, it's harder to avoid I/O, but you can easily move Symfony's cache dir to memory by overriding AppKernel's `getCacheDir()` and `getLogDir()` methods to point them to `/dev/shm`:

```php
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    // ...

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        if (in_array($this->environment, array('dev', 'test'))) {
            return '/dev/shm/appname/cache/' .  $this->environment;
        }

        return parent::getCacheDir();
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        if (in_array($this->environment, array('dev', 'test'))) {
            return '/dev/shm/appname/logs';
        }

        return parent::getLogDir();
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/08/19/speedup_symfony2_on_vagrant_boxes.html

Comment: Since APC caches your files in memory, there's no I/O (well, just the first time). Anyway, that's like trying to put all your PHP soure files to Memcached, S3, wahtever...

Comment: APC caches the opcode, but doesn't it still hit each file to check modification times incase they've been changed? There may be some value in pointing the cache dir to /dev/shm to have them stored on ramdisk even for these tiny I/O operations. (I can't imagine any of this would matter at all in any practical sense... but interesting thought none-the-less)

Comment: No, on prod you should have apc.stat disabled to avoid checks for modification times.

Comment: @JakubZalas Distributed cache can be advantageous here as well. If you are running multiple webservers

Comment: why downvoting? @Ascherer distributed cache would give an additional overhead (since it's distributed).

Comment: I actually didn't downvote. Super bump. But the overhead on this would by HIGHLY negligible, if the distributed cache is on the same network

Comment: I didn't say you did. I only asked a question and a reply to you in a single comment ;)

Comment: Concerning, shared cached, it's quite dangerous since absolute paths are hardcoded in the compiled cache. Thus, you need to ensure that the filesystem hierarchy is **exactly** the same on all machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gaufrette (https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette, https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle) to  create a virtual filesystem from almost any storage possible (APC, memory, S3, FTP, SQL db). Then set cache-dir to `gaufrette://s3` for example.

Comment: Gaufrette won't let you to store Symfony's cache in memory.