# Move the Symfony2 Cache directory off the filesystem?

Tags: symfony

I'm looking to remove the dependency on the filesystem for my symfony2 cache directory (`app/cache/*`) and I don't see a clear path to doing that by modifying services or anything of that nature.

Ultimately, I'm attempting to use Symfony on a filesystem that cannot be altered. In the past I've been able to re-map twig templates and intl files to the database, and in theory this should be possible with the cache (and it already is with the logs).

Is there a way I can make the framework use another service like Redis, a database, or even just keep it in RAM for the life of the script?

I've attempted to run a cache:warmup command also, however, writing to the filesystem still happens even with the cache pre-generated.

The parameter used by everything is defined in the framework as `kernel.cache_dir`

Comment: Similar question to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779370/storing-symfony-2-cache-elsewere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779370/storing-symfony-2-cache-elsewere).

Comment: @kba Thanks for the reference link. I was playing with that concept earlier, however, the system I'm running on is only posix-like, not unix-like, and so I don't even have a /dev/null I can point to. The real goal here is to run without a mutable file structure (even if it's just in /dev/shm)