# Using Redis for Symfony /var/cache and /var/logs

Tags: caching, redis, symfony, homestead

I'm running Symfony 3.* instances in Homestead with PHP 7.1 and recently switched the cache and logs directory away from my main folder as the NFS syncing was going crazy and greatly diminished the performance of the whole installation.

I was wondering if I could fully dispatch logging and caching that usually go to `./var/` to Redis in some way through the configuration or a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the logging to turn it off, or down - or elect to not write it to a file, and instead send it to Redis, or other sources. There are many optional targets that Monolog can use, usually with a support library and configuration.

The cached files are not designed to be written elsewhere though. Because they are being written to disk, they can then be cached by OpCache.

It doesn't mean that `var/*` has to be written to a real disk however. If you have shared memory, to be used as a ram-disk (also known as tmpfs). An app can be quite easily altered to use that - for cache and/or log files:

```php
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    // ...

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        if (in_array($this->environment, array('dev', 'test'))) {
            return '/dev/shm/appname/cache/' .  $this->environment;
        }
        return parent::getCacheDir();
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        if (in_array($this->environment, array('dev', 'test'))) {
            return '/dev/shm/appname/logs';
        }
        return parent::getLogDir();
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/08/19/speedup_symfony2_on_vagrant_boxes.html via https://stackoverflow.com/a/10784563